# Debate on question closure: “Why is MCStacker not giving me the correct command?”

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question, reopen

After [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/372403/250180) question got closed, I became quite an advocate for getting it reopened. We’ve had quite the discussion in the question comments, and I’d like to start an official debate on it.

Click on the above link for a refresher of the question topic.

Here is my original argument for the question:

> I seriously do not believe this is a duplicate. This is about manipulating MCStacker, not manipulating the command itself. The OP even says that they rarely make their commands themselves, and that they always generate them. The duplicate you have linked is mainly for tweaking the raw command, which I can't see connecting to how you would fix it in MCStacker.

## Current status

I have made several attempts to reopen the question, including making some comments, and making some edits. One of the edits I made was not ideal, and has been reverted. Now I have made another edit, which is being contested by [pppery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/185203/). I have provided my defence for it, but it has been deleted.

What are your thoughts on this argument above?

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem with the linked question lies in the *assumption* that the OP cannot (make the effort to) decipher the commands, which can and should not be something we as a community have to solve. If things remain unclear, the OP can always ask another question. The crux of the problem - based on the error messages - seems to be addressed in the duplicate question, hence the closing. **Whether or not this information is practically useful to the OP is not a matter that should prevent us from closing questions as duplicates.**

I also don't really get the goal of your post here on meta.
It seems you want to open up the matter to a larger audience, but there's barely any argumentation here, and you seem to want to reserve the answer to the outcome of the debate, but that's not how question threads (should) work - there is not even really a question here, it just says "debate".
I don't want to suggest we have a debate about the merit of that single question here, since the debate has taken place.
**What I can suggest is that you make a stronger argument here, by describing the issue, arguing for your position and point of view, and rebuking the arguments used against the reopening.**

Comment: "Whether or not this information is practically useful to the OP is not a matter that should prevent us from closing questions as duplicates." -- Especially when it comes to code aspects, there needs to be an assumption the asker has the ability to recognize and adapt existing answers to meet their needs.  An expectation of being able to just copy and paste answers to solve that exact issue misunderstands our purpose.

Comment: Thanks. There is just too much going on! I’ve tried to do to many things at once, and that’s my fault. Please forgive me.

Comment: Right now, there is a chat room open, this meta thread open, and a long comment discussion on the original post. What do you suggest we do with these parts?

Comment: You can just leave them be. This meta thread as well as the original post including its comments can be closed or used as future reference, and the chat room will 'fade away' eventually, methinks. And don't worry, there's nothing to forgive: it's awesome you're getting yourself this involved :)